# Program runs three times, gets three different results

Tags: c#

I wrote this program to cut up EDI files into their own files but it is not doing it consistantly. Sometimes it breaks a file with three sections into only two sections, and other times it finds all three sections.

Can anyone explain to me why it is behaving this way? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace chomp
{
    class Program
    {
        static string GenerateFileName(string context)
        {
            return context + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".edi"; 
        } 
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            string delimiter = "\r\n\r\n";
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a file name: ");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string fileName = (args[0]);
                    if (File.Exists(fileName)){
                    System.IO.StreamReader myFile =
                    new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
                    string FileStream = myFile.ReadToEnd();
                    myFile.Close();

                    string myFileName = GenerateFileName("DOC");
                    string[] FSPart = FileStream.Split(new string[] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    foreach (string s in FSPart)
                    {
                        string newAwesomeFN = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".edi"; 
                        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(newAwesomeFN))
                        {
                        }

                        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(newAwesomeFN);
                        file.WriteLine(s);
                        file.Close();
                    }
                    return 0;
                    } else {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Filename "+ fileName+ " does not exist!");
                        return 0;
                    } // closes else + if File.Exists
                }
                catch (System.FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("A Filename must be entered!");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        } //closes main
    } //closes program
} //closes main
```

Comment: Is it inconsistent with the same file? or different files?

Comment: Your file is in UTF8 encode?

Comment: What is fs used for, why do you have a using statement like that, that opens a file stream and does nothing maybe that cussing the unpredictable behaver?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With some luck, it might have generated the same filename many times. Your "Random file name" might be not random enough. Try using simple static counter like

```
public static int filenumber = 0;
```

and increase it every time you generate a filename instead of using `DateTime` with `fff` precision*). Do it and retry running you program. If it was the problem, it will fix it.

If this does not fix it, I'll think about it more ;)

*) you see, the `DateTime` is actually refreshed once in a while, like every few milliseconds. Your loop surely loops faster. It is not "high-performance" timestamp. If you want a better 'timestamper', use `Stopwatch`. It is high-performance, maybe not best, but good.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is running too fast to generate random filenames.  I was able to reproduce it on my system.  I altered your code to use GUIDs for the filename to make sure there was no chance of duplicates and it seems to have resolved it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;



namespace chomp
{
    class Program
    {
        static string GenerateFileName(string context)
        {
            return context + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".edi"; // DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".edi";
        }
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            string delimiter = "\r\n\r\n";
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a file name: ");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {

                try
                {

                    string fileName = (args[0]);
                    if (File.Exists(fileName))
                    {
                        System.IO.StreamReader myFile =
                        new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
                        string FileStream = myFile.ReadToEnd();
                        myFile.Close();

                        string[] FSPart = FileStream.Split(new string[] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                        foreach (string s in FSPart)
                        {
                            string myFileName = GenerateFileName("DOC");
                            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(myFileName, false);
                            file.WriteLine(s);
                            file.Close();
                        }
                        return 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Filename " + fileName + " does not exist!");
                        return 0;
                    } // closes else + if File.Exists
                }
                catch (System.FormatException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("A Filename must be entered!");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        } //closes main

    } //closes program
} //closes main
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are manually determining where the line breaks occur which is not as reliable.

1. Remove `delimiter` variable
2. Remove the use `StreamReader` and splitting on the delimiter
3. Replace it with [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

File.ReadAllLines will give you the list of lines which you can then iterate through using foreach.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl If it is true that manually determining the line breaks is unreliable, then isn't it also true that each time you read the file, it could be splitting on different line breaks?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I agree. But when a file is created and saved to disk, there is a possibility that it will have different line endings. For example some would end in `\r\n` and some in `\r\n\r\n`. This is why I suggested using the built in `File.ReadAllLines`, instead of a hardcoded delimiter to look for. I am not saying the code won't work, but that the source files could be messed up.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I was just saying it was something to look for in my original answer and you said that it was illogical (and retracted and are now on the attack). its ok.

Comment: hmm.. so, probably, we should do a purge. I hope you don't mind;)